# Content pushed to the right side when printing using AdminLTE on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, adminlte

When printing a page using the [AdminLTE](https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html) theme on Chrome, the content is pushed to the right side of the page. This only affects Chrome (safari & Firefox display the content full width) and only when actually printing. The "media print" emulation will display the content correctly, making this near impossible to debug beside trial and error.

I added this to my css file, but it doesn't change anything.

```
@media print {
    .content-wrapper, .right-side, .main-footer {
        margin-left: 0 px !important;
        -webkit-transition: none !important;
        transition: none !important;
    }
}
```

**EDIT** : You can actually test it out in their own demo pages here : https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/pages/tables/data.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with Chrome 53 on MacOS and is now fixed on Chrome 54.

Comment: No, it was not fixed and still an issue after 6 years